# Navigation does not find xml Menu

Tags: android, menu

I'm new in android developing and just wanted to try out a simple bottom navigation, so I looked up the official tutorial (Link to tutorial: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView ) on how to do it and added dependencies in my gradle File:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

But I keep getting the error that the resource is not found, even it is there!
[image]

I just don't understand what is happening - I already tried to clean, sync, restart, etc. 
When I introduce the whole path (therefor C:/... ) I get the error
C:/...  is incompatible with attribute (attr) reference [weak].

I have also tried to replace **app:menu** with **design:menu** as I found in some other tutorials, but than I get the error that design:menu is an unknown attribute..

Comment: remove .xml extension in app:menu

app:menu="@menu/menu_main"

Comment: place your cursor on the bottom navigation view declaration where the red line is present and press alt + enter at the same time ,, it will give you suggestions as to what the problem is and how to solve it

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to place .xml extension just do

```
app:menu="@menu/menu_main"
```